# Oracle - ORA-38101: Invalid column in the INSERT VALUES Clause on Merge

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, upsert

I'm trying to do an upsert using merge and I'm getting an error message: `Oracle - ORA-38101: Invalid column in the INSERT VALUES Clause on Merge: "MY_TABLE"."MYCOL2"`, even thought the table and column names indicated in the error are correct.

```sql
declare
   var1 varchar2(50) := 'var1';
   var2 varchar2(50) := 'var2';

   procedure ins
      (mycol1 IN VARCHAR2,
       mycol2 IN VARCHAR2)
   is
   BEGIN
      LOOP
         BEGIN
        MERGE INTO my_table USING dual ON
        (     MYCOL1 = mycol1
          AND MYCOL2 = mycol2
        )
           WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
              MYCOL1 = mycol1,
              MYCOL2 = mycol2
           WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
              (MYCOL1, MYCOL2) 
                  VALUES ( mycol1, mycol2 );
                  EXIT; -- success? -> exit loop
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN -- the entry was concurrently deleted
               NULL; -- exception? -> no op, i.e. continue looping
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN -- an entry was concurrently inserted
               NULL; -- exception? -> no op, i.e. continue looping
         END;
      END LOOP;
   END; 
begin
   ins (var1, var2);
end;
```

Comment: you need a **subquery** such as `MERGE INTO my_table USING ( SELECT <some_val> AS mycol1, <some_val> AS mycol2 dual ) ON` rather than `MERGE INTO my_table USING dual ON` ...

Comment: @Tejash is absolutely correct but a little explanation may helps.  Oracle is case insensitive on names (tables, views, variables, ...) , unless double quoted. Thus MYCOL1 and mycol1 **are the same**. And a table column is always chosen over a variable, so your update would just set the columns to their current value.  Additionally, you have a logic issue. You have a loop that the MERGE runs in. But your data values DO NOT change during the loop, so if you take the MATCHED leg, your loop will never end. MERGE is a single DML statement and should not be in a loop unless the data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Dont use the variable names which are same as column name of the table.
- Your `MATCHED` clause is doing nothing.
- in `USING` clause, there must be some query as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: OK, yes. I solved it by adding a query in the USING part and there also had to add aliases with `AS` in the fields.